# If $V$ is finite dimensional and $T:V \to V , S:V \to V$ are normal linear transformations and $TS=ST$ then they share a common basis of egienvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is over the field $\mathbb{R}$ then this is not always true, because in $\mathbb{R}$ if a linear transformation $T$ is normal , then it is not always true that $T$ diagonalizable and thus not having a basis for $V$ that contains eigenvectors of $T$

But if $V$ is over the field $\mathbb{C}$ then I think this is true. I would like to get a clue please on how to proceed.

Comment: Any two commuting diagonal matrices are simultaneously diagonalisable.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take a basis of $V$ that consists of eigenvectors of $T$ and see what you get from $ST=TS$. Can this basis also consist of eigenvectors of $S$?